# Git submodules. Как использовать определенную версию даже при изменении в main ветке

Tags: git, github

Всем привет. У меня вопрос по поводу git submodules. У нас есть два репозитория, к примеру. Один с основным кодом, а второй репозиторий мы хотим использовать в качестве сабмодуля и этот репозиторий имеет релиз с тэгом v1.0.0. Можно ли вообще сделать так, чтобы в работе использовалась именно эта версия, даже если кто-то(случайно, к примеру) запушил изменения в мэйн ветку? Я добавлял в .gitmodules строчку branch = sha1(sha коммита), это не сработало.

Comment: кратко: ничего не надо делать. [подробно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500404/4827341)

Comment: То есть нельзя сделать так, чтобы в основном проекте использовался(автоматически) код определенного релиза(1.0.0 в нашем случае) из сабмодуля?

Comment: это происходит по умолчанию, если явно не указан параметр branch. к какому коммиту привязали — тот и будет использоваться после клонирования.